# Sqlite Rounding

Tags: sqlite, rounding

```
SUM(ROUND((price)-((price* TAX)/100 + purchaseprice),2)) as'"+PROFIT+"'
```

"**PROFIT**" without Rounding is 15.0057  and with it is 15 instead of 15.01

"**TAX**" is the percentage for example "19%" but stored without the "%" no problems there.

price and purchaseprice are stored as numeric.

What do i have to change to get 15.01 instead of 15. A better solution for me would be to format "PROFIT"  somehow with `NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Did you try  ROUND(SUM(price - (price* TAX/100) + purchaseprice),2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rounded probably prematurely.
So

`ROUND(SUM(price - (price* TAX/100) + purchaseprice),2)`

should give the wanted result.

Comment: In this case it works but look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136252/sqlite-calculation-with-same-values-different-results  i have still problems