# SQLite Calculation with same Values different Results

Tags: sql, sqlite, math

My table contains this values

```
productName | purchasePrice | tax | price 
------------+---------------+-----+--------
Product 1   | 5099          | 16  | 10099
Product 1   | 5099          | 16  | 10099
Product 1   | 5099          | 16  | 10099
Product 1   | 5099          | 16  | 10099
Product 2   | 5099          | 19  | 10099
Product 2   | 5099          | 19  | 10099
Product 2   | 5099          | 19  | 10099
```

My Calculation for the Total Profit is this

```
SUM( price- ( price * tax/100.0  + purchasePrice)) as Profit
```

Result as Profit = **22780.210000000006**

My Calculation for the Profit of every Product is this

```
SUM(price- (price*TAX/100.0 + purchasePrice)) as Profit GROUP BY productName
```

Result as Profit for Product 1 = **13536,6**
Result as Profit for Product 2 =  **9243,57**

Total **22780,17**

I have to round this Values and divide them by /100.0 because I've read that it is better to not store the values with floating points in Sqlite.

I do the rounding and /100.0 like this

**Round for Total** with the Result of = **227.8**

```
ROUND((SUM( price- ( price * tax/100.0  + purchasePrice)))/100 ,2) as Profit
```

Round for every Product

```
ROUND((SUM( price- ( price * tax/100.0  + purchasePrice)))/100 ,2) as Profit GROUP BY productName
```

Product 1 result = **135,37**
Product 2 result = **92,44**

Total                **227,81** but the **Round for Total** gives me the Result of = **227.8**

Any ideas?

Comment: I think values of first group by is wrong - check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8deb9/3 (`22780,17` => `22780,21`) ;).

Comment: Thank you shAt.t,  How can i fix this?

Comment: `3.3 + 3.3 + 3.4 = 10` and `Round(3.3, 0) + Round(3.3, 0) + Round(3.4, 0) = 9` - with using round you will loose some values sum of rounded values is not always equal to sum of non-rounded values ;).

Comment: i get the wrong result even if i remove the Round -> My Calculation for the Profit of every Product is this SUM(price- (price*TAX/100.0 + purchasePrice)) as Profit GROUP BY productName
Result as Profit for Product 1 = 13536,6
Result as Profit for Product 2 = 9243,57

Total 22780,17

Comment: If you use rounding, you always loose some accuracy. Depending when and with what rounding function you work, you get different results.

Comment: Thank you but cant you guys see that it makes no difference if i round or not. Thats the reason why i wrote both codes with rounding and without.

Comment: I get `13536.64`, not `13536,6`.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of SQL-lite the below code works with Round

```
select SUM(Profit) from (
select productName,round((SUM(price- (price*TAX/100.0 + purchasePrice)))/100 ,2)
as Profit
from test
GROUP BY productName
)x
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8eba1/25